# Display Wordpress Content based on the current theme

Tags: php, wordpress, smarty

I was wondering if Wordpress has a tag system similar to WHMCS', I'm fixing a clients website for him, and a lot of this content is HTML/CSS. I was wondering if there were any statements like WHMCS' {if $loggedin} Some content here {else} Other content here {/if}.

I'm trying to make a mobile version for his site, so there will be two separate themes (standard and mobile) and that's what I want to achieve, if at all possible, have like a {if $standardtemplate} Main content here {else} Mobile content here {/if}, as his content contains a lot of large images and HTML, it's going to make a relatively simple job very hard.

If Wordpress doesn't contain anything like that, is it possible to implement? And how?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you develop two separate templates for contents? you can switch them simply by using http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_theme

Comment: Would you mind explaining to me how I can use the: switch_theme( $template, $stylesheet ) to swap themes? Where would I place this? What needs to be changed?

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is, all of the content is done in a HTML markup, div's, styles, et cetera. So I need to be able to swap content based on the current theme.

Comment: Why don't you just download  a plugin , there a whole bunch of them that convert a mobile experience or load separate templates for mobile.